# A doubt on Doppler effect

Tags: doppler-effect

As I learnt freq. observed by a observer from a moving source is given by $$f=f_0(1+v_s/v)^{-1}$$
If $$v_s=-v$$ f is infinity.Whats going on? Will Doppler effect will be observed if the source say is a fighter plane moving at mach 1 towards observer? My intuition is that Doppler effect is not observed am I correct?

Comment: That is what a sonic boom is, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this means, that you $can not$ get the information from a source if you move from it with the speed the information travels.

If $v_s < v$, than you get $f < 0$, which is nonsense, right? It just means that the wave which contains information (sound, light, etc) cannot reach you since you travel so fast!

Comment: $v_s$ in this case is the speed of the *source* (not the observer).  So the information emitted by something approaching you faster than the speed of the waves does reach you.  $f < 0$ isn't quite nonsense: it means that the order in which the information reaches you is *reversed* relative to how it was emitted.

Comment: I can't quite agree with you, Ben, since the Doppler effect effectively is based on the comparison between the speed of sound (light) and the speed of emitter. There is no difference between the movement of the observer and the source since you can apply a simple Galileo transformation (assuming the non-relativistic scenario) and make another one moving instead of standing, up to the sign in velocity vector.

Comment: No, you have it quite backward.  For light, there is no distinction between observer and source: that is the basic tenet of relativity.  For waves in a medium, such as we are discussing here, there is absolutely a difference: the assumed frame is the one in which the medium is stationary, and the frequency shift is different if the source is moving than if the observer is.  In particular, if the observer is moving away from the source faster than the waves travel, the signal will never catch up.  If the source is moving away, its waves will propagate to the observer just fine.